# Как при нажатии кнопки изменить значение у элемента который только что добавился этой кнопкой?

Tags: javascript, html, jquery

Есть inputы значение которых заполнено из базы данных, сейчас если нажать на кнопку add, она добавляет инпут со значением первого, как сделать так, чтоб добавлялся пустой инпут?

```
$(document)
            .ready(function () {
                const variant = $('#phone')
                    .clone(true);
                const variant2 = $('#emails')
                    .clone(true);
                $('#add')
                    .click(function () {
                        $(variant)
                            .clone(true)
                            .appendTo('#variants')
                            .fadeIn('slow')
                            .focus();
                    });
                $('#add2')
                    .click(function () {
                        $(variant2)
                            .clone(true)
                            .appendTo('#variants2')
                            .fadeIn('slow')
                            .focus();

                    });
            });

<div id="variants">
                    <?php foreach($numbers as $number):
                        if($number->user_id == $_SESSION['user_id']):
                        ?>
                    <div class="form-group" id="phone">
                        <div class="controls">
                            <input type="checkbox"  name="publish_phone[]"> <label>Publish field</label>
                            <input type="text"  class="form-control"  name="numbers[]"  id="ad" value="<?php echo $number->number; ?>">
                        </div>
                    </div>
                    <?php
                    endif;
                    endforeach; ?>
                </div>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

обнулите `value` и будет все ок

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  const variant = $('.phone');
  $('#add').click(function() {
    variant.clone(true)
      .appendTo('#variants')
      .fadeIn('slow')
      .find('input[type=text]')
      .val('')
      .focus();
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="variants">
  <div class="form-group phone">
    <div class="controls">
      <input type="checkbox" name="publish_phone[]"> <label>Publish field</label>
      <input type="text" class="form-control" name="numbers[]" id="ad" value="100">
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
<button id="add">add</button>
```